# ¿Cómo crear portales en Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

En `React` puedes usar `portales` asignándoles los ids a otros divs que no sea el main y asi trabajar bien con los `z-index` como modales, con Next.js ¿como seria en este caso?.
Se agregaría un div con el id el documento extendido?

esto sería en react:

html:

```
<div id="modal"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

app.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
                {ReactDOM.createPortal(<h1>Modal, esta fuera del div main</h1>, document.getElementById('modal'))}
                <header className="App-header">
                ....
            </header>
            </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Ya que en `Nextjs` se extiend el documento y al aplicación queda en `<Main />`

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
          <Html>
            <Head />
            <body className="my-body-class">
              <Main />
              <NextScript />
            </body>
          </Html>
        );
    }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Comment: intentaste con esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65980052/4717133 me avisas si te sirve.

Comment: @Albert Arias te recomiendo leer este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaiE_K32gBE

Comment: muchas gracias @JeanGotopo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigue los siguientes pasos:

1. Crear un file con el nombre `_document.js` en el folder de `/pages`, y aqui tienes que renderizar el HTML y dentro del body tienes que tener en este caso `<div id=tooltip>`

[image: step1]

2. Luego, dentro del componente tienes que crear el `hook` con el estado inicial en `false` y luego cambiarlo a `true` con el `useEffect` y devolverlo nuevamente en `false` y pues si es `true` crearemos el portal de lo contrario devolveremos `null`:

[image: step2]

3. Por último, tenemos que agregar todos los elementos que queremos mostrar dentro del portal y pasarle el selector con el id con el div que creamos anteriormente.

[[image: step33]

Si aún no te ha quedado claro, te recomiendo mirar este [tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaiE_K32gBE)

Comment: Considera responder con código y no con imágenes.

Comment: Me parece bien, pero por eso la respuesta no es util?

Comment: Tienes razón! Disculpa, edité levemente tu respuesta para que me permitiera valorar tu respuesta.

Comment: oh vale, hice la prueba y funcionó, muchas gracias por el aporte @kemilbeltre, perdona por leer tarde

Comment: Me alegro, tranqui para eso estamos! :)